# How to add a function to all the options in various select except from one select?

Tags: jquery

I know the title it's not saying exactly what I want to do, and it can be confusing or not descriptive so if someone knows a better way to explain this in title say it!

I have this case:

```
<div id="selectable2" class="dd-container">
  <div class="dd-select">
    <input class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden" name="information2" value="something">
    <a class="dd-selected">
      SOME TEXT
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul class="dd-options dd-click-off-close">
    <li>
      **<a class="dd-option dd-option-selected">**
          <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="something"> 
          SOME TEXT
      </a>
   </li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

In this code that is not generated by me, I have a select, the previous programmer to check some data, when an option is selected, it activates a function like this:

```
$('.dd-option').click(CheckFunction);
```

Activates when this tag (inside the select) is clicked:

```
**<a class="dd-option dd-option-selected">**
```

So the thing I have to do is to duplicate that select, which I already did but I dont want it to activate that function like the rest of selects.

I duplicated that select like this:

```
var $options = $("#selectable1 > option").clone();

$('#selectable2').append($options);
```

So I have the same content as the other with that same class generated, so is there a way in jquery to put that I want to add that function to all except the one which select id is "selectable2"?

Something like this:

```
$(".dd-option:not('#selectable2')").click(CheckFunction);
```

But it's not possible because the select is which has the id not the tag `<a>` which is the one selected by the class and added that click function:

```
**<a class="dd-option dd-option-selected">**
```

If that's not possible how do i check once in the function that the parent id of the tag `<a>` clicked is "selectable2", so i know that I don't want the code to execute when is coming from that select.

Something like this:

```
CheckFunction (event) {
     if(event.parent.id != "selectable2"){
        //function code
     }
}
```

I hope I explained myself well. Any questions, ask me please!

Comment: `$('#selectable2').off('click');`?

Comment: It's not working for me :(

Comment: `$('#selectable2').append($options);` says that you are appending `<option>` to a `<div>`.  Are you sure that is what you meant?

Comment: Yes, when I wrote the code I put a `<select>` tag but because i add an specific class ('ddslick') it has a plugin that transform it like I show in code and add the rest of things `<select name="something2" id="selectable2" class="ddslick selectable2"></select>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: You can add one class to options after cloning and filter these elements from click handler

```
var $options = $("#selectable1 > option").clone();
$options.addClass('NoClick');
$('#selectable2').append($options);
```

jQuery click handler

```
$(document).on("click",".dd-option:not(.NoClick)",CheckFunction);
```

Comment: It doesn't add the class 'noClick' anywhere.

Comment: $option must be a jquery object and it should add class. check console error if any or try `$option = $($option);` before addClass line

Comment: If I add `$option = $($option);` like that in singular it throws error, I tryed `$options = $($options);` and still doesn't add the class 'noClick':
                                     
`var $options = $("#selectable1 > option").clone();
$options = $($options);
$options.addClass('noClick');
$('#selectable2').append($options);`




I have it like this and still doesn't work. And no console errors shown.

Comment: can you please share working jsfiddle with problem you are facing so that i can take a look and see

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/92zb3x7p/26/

I can't make it to work but there is the code that is working on the page. Here It's just not applying the ddslick plugin that works well on the page.

Comment: I already fixed it, I just added the class after with `$('#selectable2 a').addClass('noClick');` Thanks for the help!

Comment: great!! .. happy to help you :)